# Issue changing the width of Fixed Space Bar Button when the device it's rotated

Tags: swift, ios8, uibarbuttonitem

I've create two outlets to two Fixed Space Bar Buttom and then when the device it's rotated I update its width to maintain the width in portrait or landscape.

The curious thing is that it was working until a few days back, but in one moment left to work.

In the `viewWillTransitionToSize` I update the width in any case (portrait or landscape) and the values are updated because in debug time I saw it, but for some reason don't update the width.

One curious thing is if I set the width in the `viewDidLoad()` it's work good, the problem it's when the device it;s rotated, don't update the width anymore.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason my autolayout constraints are not correct at all, I clear my old constraints put a new contraints correct and like magic!!! all it's work again.

**Always need to have the constraint correct to change dynamically the Fixed Space Bar Button**